# Create Sub-Domain or Unique URL For every registered user Dynamically in CakePHP using router?

Tags: cakephp

I want to create a sub-domain for every registered user dynamically.Like as follows
For e.g my site is http://example.com/users/view And Joe is the register user then the all of my web site URL should be accessible to Joe like as http://joe.example.com/user/view

Answer (score 0):

So from [this document page](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html), you could probably use something like this:

```
Router::connect(
    '/:id/view',
    ['controller' => 'Articles', 'action' => 'view'],
    ['id' => '\d+', 'pass' => ['id']]
);
```

The documentation is very thorough.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple approach involves setting up your Apache `VirtualHost` to catch all requests, regardless of the subdomain used, by adding the following:

```
ServerAlias *
```

Now we have to extract the subdomain and store it as a global variable when a request is made.

In `AppController.php` add:

```
function beforeFilter() {
    list ($subdomain,$domain)= explode('.',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
    Configure::write('username',$subdomain);
}
```

In `UsersController.php` we read this variable and fetch the user.

```
public function view(){
    $user=$this->User->findByUsername(Configure::read('username'));
    $this->set(compact('user'));
}
```

<sub>Note: Code is untested and lacks error handling.</sub>